# NODE JS, WebSocket как со стороны сервера производить обновление данных на страничке?

Tags: node.js, websocket

я очень новичок в веб технологиях, подскажите пожалуйста, как с серверной части, где запущен вебсокет сервер на node js передавать информацию на клиентскую страничку без запроса со стороны клиента, обновлять информацию?
У меня датчик ардуины через последовательный порт передает данные на сервер по таймингу или по событию (не важно), хочу их с сервера передавать на страничку браузера. Хотя бы просто строкой в тело страницы или в поле формы.

PS: смотрел примеры где, со стороны клиента посылается сообщение, а со стороны сервера возвращается ответ, но там нужно именно вручную обновлять страницу что бы приходил ответ. Пытался посылать данные с сервера из цикла, они вроде отсылаются, но не отображаются на странице, а если обновить страницу, то они высыпают все, что были отосланы... Еще в таком случае ошибка вылетает на сервере- что то вроде слишком много слушателей (listener).
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

1. Сервер должен сгенерировать событие

   socket.emit('message', someData);
2. Клиент должен быть подписан на событие

   socket.on('message', listener);
   function listener(data) {
       console.log(data);
   }

Это пример реализации для socket.io

Comment: Я начал с модуля WebSocket (WS), хотелось бы все же с ним разобраться... Наверное параллельно буду и с помощью socket.io пробовать, вроде распространенный модуль.